# Do threads in rails automatically open database connections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a rails app running on Heroku that makes use of threads, and it occasionally runs into database connection errors. Is this just because I am accessing the database within the threads or does each thread automatically open a database connection? I would like to learn more about threading in rails, and any resources are appreciated.

Comment: What errors precisely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question varies largely depending on how many instances you have running, how many requests your receiving, and more importantly your database. Databases can and will have a maximum number of concurrent connections. You can read more about Heroku/concurrent connections [here in the Heroku official documentary](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections), it's probably more informative than what I can tell you in a single comment.

That being said, your question was a little vague and it's hard to figure out what's going on. Can you tell us a little more about what error you're getting (like the specific error) and maybe a small backtrace? Are you getting these errors on the same pages or different pages? Would you say your site is particularly high traffic?

Comment: I'm actually trying to deal with an older issue I worked around, and I do not have the exact trace anymore, but I believe this was the specific error: FATAL:  too many connections for role "[role name]" which I understand to some extent, but I am wondering whether this db connection is because the threads open a connection automatically or only if they try to access the database. Like if I make no DB requests in a thread, is it still opening a connection?

Comment: @spitfire109 No, if nothing in the request actually needs data from the DB it won't make one.

Comment: @JoshEmory does this still applies to rails 5? (not checking out a new connection from the db pool if it no db data is needed)

Comment: @OscarMederos I believe this does still apply in Rails 5, yes